# Rails 3 authentication with OpenID, Twitter or Facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, openid, ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic

Can you suggest some working example of it? I tried Authlogic and Devise withous success.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**UPDATE - June 2011** - I have been using the [omniauth gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/omniauth) recently and I think it is a better solution than using the gems suggested in this answer.  It works well with Devise and will give you everything you need in one gem.  I created an engine that combines Devise and Omniauth and adds a controller to handle the callbacks.  I have quite a few changes planned for the gem and right now I don't consider it a stable plugin, but you may be able to reuse some of the code in the gem: https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/devise_omniauth_engine/blob/master/app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb

---

I recently got this working on Rails 3 (with some problems using OpenID).  I don't have a complete working example that you can look at on github, but here is what I am using... all of which have examples in the readme files.

**Facebook** - [fbgraph](http://github.com/nsanta/fbgraph).  Unlike Facebooker, it uses the most recent Facebook API.  And the source is very easy to understand if you feel like taking a look at the inner workings.  Look at the authentication example in the readme.  Dead simple.

**Twitter** - [twitter_oauth](http://github.com/moomerman/twitter_oauth) Again, check out the readme authentication example.  This was fairly easy to set up too.

**OpenID** - [rails/open_id_authentication](http://github.com/rails/open_id_authentication)  uses ruby-openid gem, but this repo itself is not a gem, so you will have to drop the code into your app or put in your plugin directory.  Take a look at their example in the readme and also inspect the source closely to understand what is going on (its only 130 lines of code).  I modified a good bit of it to get it to work with my authentication plugin, but I ran into some problems making it work with both Simple Registration and Attribute Exchange at the same time... but you might be able to get it to work out of the box if the rdoc example is suitable for your app.

Let me know if you have any specific questions on these.  I ran into a few problems I was able to resolve with all 3 when I was setting this up.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Are you using any general authentication plugin (like authlogic, devise, restful_authentication) with them, or have you build your own 'standard authentication' solution?

Comment: I just made my own simple auth plugin.  I don't really need all the features that devise and authlogic offer.  I looked at the source for both and picked out some things I liked to use in my own role and auth solution.  While I don't like reinventing the wheel, I always seem to learn more when I code it myself (while drawing inspiration from other solutions). Plus if I need to extend it, I don't have to dig thru other people's source fr a week to figure it out.  I am working on turning the FB/Twitter/OpenID stuff into a rails engine.  I will post it here if I get to it in the next few days.

Comment: I am unable to get the open_id_authentication working. It looks like the migrations are missing are missing. It only has a one .rb file. Am I missing something.

Comment: @iHeartDucks you don't need migrations for this.  OpenID will allow you to use third party sites to authenticate against.  You can get back info like email address and name, but it is up to you to store those in your database.  All OpenID does is connects to another service (Google accounts, for example) and after the user agrees to let that OpenID provider share info with your site, the OpenID provider will send you information back regarding the user.  Does that help or am I misunderstanding what you are asking?

Answer (score 4):

I spent about a week trying (unsuccessfully) to get open_id_authentication working. I was trying to use Authlogic and all the associated gems and plugins. I could not get things working the way I wanted. (Authentication would only work with the :action(/:id) route enabled, but when that was enabled, my other controllers wouldn't work because something in the plugin was stripping the params hash - very frustrating).

However, I was finally able to get OpenID working using Devise (http://github.com/plataformatec/devise) and devise_openid_authenticatable (http://github.com/nbudin/devise_openid_authenticatable). I was able to follow the readme's on both of the pages to get everything working exactly like I wanted it to. Simple. Straight forward. And Rails 3.0 compatible.

Comment: Yep, I could not get the open_id_authentication to work either. Looking into devise now.

Answer (score 2):

Devise is built on Warden, which is the correct google term. Search 'warden openid', 'warden oauth' (twitter) and http://github.com/britt/facebook-warden-strategy for facebook

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use Facebooker 2, you'll have to upgrade your Rails framework to 3.0. Ayeah Games just went through the process for the game FanSwarm (on Facebook). This is no easy task, but the blog post may give you some insight.

http://www.ayeahgames.com/blog/bid/55099/The-Horror-Upgrading-to-Rails-3

Answer (score 0):

AuthLogic has an OpenID extension.

Also, this may help: http://www.michaelhamrah.com/blog/2009/05/authlogic-and-openid-on-rails/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I've found to do this is to use [RPX NOW](https://rpxnow.com/) service.

You can find a full working example of using it with Rails3 and the RPX NOW gem at [github](https://github.com/mazur/rpx_now_example).