# Code for login with facebook in rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In my application we are providing user to login with facebook.Can any1 tell me the code for this?

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713086/rails-3-authetication-with-openid-twitter-or-facebook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this app:

https://github.com/holden/devise-omniauth-example/

Answer (score 0):

Devise 1.2 now comes with facebook login support using omniauth and works with Rails 3.0. Check out https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3a-Overview.